# How to use unittest with multifile module in python

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

I want to create the test case for check the same function in many files. Each file has the same function name but different algorithm.

I tried to create a loop for test each file in unit-test but it didnt't work.

Comment: Thank you, James Z for proof my grammar, my English is not well but I try to practice my English skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__import__('name')` will return a module. So here we can find a solution:

lib1.py, lib2.py, lib3.py:

```
def func():
    return 123
```

test.py:

```
import unittest

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bar(self):
        for name in ['lib1','lib2','lib3']:
            result=__import__(name).func()
            self.assertEqual(result, 123)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Thank you, Could you suggest me How to use unittest on python?
Because I have many cases to test the function.

Comment: @PisitNakjai just follow the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example). i have edited my code based on the docs.